# How to queue up actions and animations in Unity for turn-based combat?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a turn-based combat sequence in Unity on C# and I currently have turn switching working and inputs and AI. But I can't quite figure out how to queue it up with animations anf stuff, so that one happens after another in *ExecuteTurnActions()*;

So my question is basically, how do I structure *ExecuteTurnActions()*?

I need it to go through all Entities and play their animations according to what's going on, like:

```
// PlayAnimation is simply Animator.SetTrigger(string)
Entities[0].PlayAnimation("Attack") or Entities[0].PlayAnimation("ReceiveDamage")
```

I need to make sure that when one Entity attacks, right when the attack happens, the other Entity receives damage and plays its animation at that moment. I know there are animation events, but I'm not sure how to make it flow from one place and make sure each entity knows which entity to trigger for animation next (when attacked for example). Any suggestions?

My structure looks something like this in **pseudocode**:

```
ENTITIES_TO_CREATE = MatchMaker.GetNumberOfPlayersAndEnemies();

void Start() {

    InitializeAllThatsNeeded();
    Entities[] = new Entity[ENTITIES_TO_CREATE];  

    // In a for loop, load up stuff and populate Entities
    Entities[0].Name = MatchMaker.GetName(0);
    Entities[0].Strength = MatchMaker.GetStrength(0); // etc etc etc

}

void Update() {

    bool HaveAllEntitiesSelectedTurnAction = new bool[Entities.Length];

    // Check every frame if all Entities have selected a turn action
    for (int i = 0; i <= Entities.Length - 1; i++) {

            HaveAllEntitiesSelectedTurnAction[i] = Entities[i].isTurnActionSelected;

        }

    // If the Entity that goes first has its action selected, then let the rest select theirs
    if(Entities[EntityHasFirstTurn].TurnActionSelected) {

        //All logic happens here, if Entity happens to be player then the player
        //is allowed input, if enity is NPC then generate hit value etc.

        // isTurnActionSelected set in this part

        // Now if all have selected their action, execute them in order
        if(HaveAllEntitiesSelectedTurnAction.All(x => x) {

            ExecuteTurnActions();

        }

    }   

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To prioritize events I would suggest using a [priority queue](https://www.dotnetperls.com/queue) data structure.

As for `ExecuteTurnActions()`, it should only set appropriate flags of an Animator Component (based on the queue, most likely). You might want each entity to have its own event queue which interacts with its own Animator.

Building a state machine for all your animations is what you need to do first. Setting certain states will allow Unity to handle all the transitions. To learn more about the Animator and handling its states look [here](https://learn.unity.com/course/introduction-to-3d-animation-systems).

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is not longer up to day because the 2nd link no longer works.